# Calculate distance along line, closest to other point (aka "project")

Tags: java, gis

I have a `LineString` (string of coordinates) made up of many points and I want to calculate the distance along the line (from the first point to the last, directionality is important) that is closest to a `Point` much like this says it does:   ["project()" calculation](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#object.project)

It would be great if I did not have to use any third party libraries, I realize some exist that would do this easily.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show us some code? It is easily doable, but you need to think through the math and once you have that then its an easy matter of writing the code for the math.

Comment: @sorifiend I can go line by line (connecting the points of the linestring) and find the closest point on each one and then find the distance to the point. Then take whichever point was closest and use this. Then measure the distance down the lines by taking the segments before it, adding them, and then add the partial segment of the line with the selected point. But this sounds over complicated, and slow for something that has probably been done very efficiently before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linear Referencing is what you are looking for. From your comment it does sound complicated, but it is still a seriously simple piece of math/code when you break it down and then just add a loop to run through your points to work out the closest segment.

Below is a nice code pulled from a google search....
You can use it to find the closest point on a line segment using: `Util.getClosestPointOnSegment(Point ss, Point se, Point p)`

Code:

```
import java.awt.Point;

public class Util{

  /**
   * Returns closest point on segment to point
   * @param ss - segment start point
   * @param se - segment end point
   * @param p - point to found closest point on segment
   * @return closest point on segment to p
   */
  public static Point getClosestPointOnSegment(Point ss, Point se, Point p)
  {
    return getClosestPointOnSegment(ss.x, ss.y, se.x, se.y, p.x, p.y);
  }

  /**
   * Returns closest point on segment to point
   * @param sx1 - segment x coord 1
   * @param sy1 - segment y coord 1
   * @param sx2 - segment x coord 2
   * @param sy2 - segment y coord 2
   * @param px - point x coord
   * @param py - point y coord
   * @return closets point on segment to point
   */
  public static Point getClosestPointOnSegment(int sx1, int sy1, int sx2, int sy2, int px, int py)
  {
    double xDelta = sx2 - sx1;
    double yDelta = sy2 - sy1;

    if ((xDelta == 0) && (yDelta == 0))
    {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Segment start equals segment end");
    }

    double u = ((px - sx1) * xDelta + (py - sy1) * yDelta) / (xDelta * xDelta + yDelta * yDelta);

    final Point closestPoint;
    if (u < 0)
    {
      closestPoint = new Point(sx1, sy1);
    }
    else if (u > 1)
    {
      closestPoint = new Point(sx2, sy2);
    }
    else
    {
      closestPoint = new Point((int) Math.round(sx1 + u * xDelta), (int) Math.round(sy1 + u * yDelta));
    }
    return closestPoint;
  }
}
```

Obviously you still need to write some code to work out the closest segment to check, and still add the lengths, but this will get you started.

Example taken from:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/Returnsclosestpointonsegmenttopoint.htm

Comment: I'll accept the answer if no one else comes along, but I was looking for something more complete because I already understand your solution. Still thank you for laying it out