# Solving for the closest point within designated area

Tags: java, algorithm, linear-programming

Trying to wrap my head around a problem I am trying to solve. I can't imagine I'm the first one that has solved something like this. I'm fairly certain its a linear programming problem. I'm working in Java and trying to come up with an efficient runtime solution for this.

The idea is I have a shape. Could be a rectangle, could be a polygon, etc. The shape has a list of points (x,y) that define its 'area'. The overall goal of this system is to find the closest point to the person within the shapes designated area so the person knows the fastest way to get into the zone

I then have another point (x,y), that is a person.  I am trying to solve for the closest area point within the shape to the person, and be able to do it efficiently at runtime.

For example (in these examples lets say the nearest point you could snap to is a .5 increment).
In this example, I'd say the solution to this problem should simply be 1,1. That is the closest valid point within the shape. If you were trying to tell the person the closet point it within this shape, That would be 1,1.
[image: Example 1]

In this example, I'd expect the solution to be 1, .5 as your closest point to the person
[image: Example 2]

In this example, your answer would just be whatever your current position is. You are already in the zone.
[image: Example 3]

Comment: These articles [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578/how-can-i-determine-whether-a-2d-point-is-within-a-polygon) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40352842/calculate-distance-along-line-closest-to-other-point-aka-project) _may_ be of interest.

Comment: Note that the examples you gave use an axis-aligned rectangle; if you only care about axis-aligned rectangles, the mathematical formulas are going to be a lot simpler and easier to implement in a programming language than if you care about the more general cases of a non-necessarily-axis-aligned rectangle, the even more general case of any convex polygon, or the even more general case of any polygon.

Comment: You had the intuition to put the tag linear-programming on your question. Good intuition. In the case of a convex polygon, this problem can be written as a simple quadratic objective, linear constraints program: simply find the point P(x, y) that minimizes the distance (x-x0)^2 + (y-y0)^2 while being inside the convex polygon (defined by one linear inequality ((yA - yB)(x-xA) + (xB-xA)(y-yA)) >= 0 per side AB). But that approach is not going to work for a non-convex polygon.

Comment: Are all your shapes convex?

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you are looking for is how to find [the distance between a point and a line segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849211/shortest-distance-between-a-point-and-a-line-segment)

You could easily check for all the lines that define the shape, and from that determine the actual closest point, as it would always be on one of those lines. Except of course, if when the point is already inside.

If you need any further help feel free to comment. Cheers ;)

Comment: ah. good point. any idea for then solving for the closest point once I pick a line segment?  I guess it could be some basic geometry. Pick a line segment and then draw a line? trying to think of how to quantify it.

Comment: other thing I'm thinking is how to verify the point is within the shape

Comment: Once you know the segment *and* the distance, its a simple case of using the segment's formula y = mx+b, using that to get a general point on the line: (x, mx+b). Now you have two points ( the original one and the segment's general one) and the distance between them.  So all that's left is to solve for x, ( the x of the general point [x, mx+b]. d = squareRoot[(x1 - x)^2 + (y1 - mx+b)^2].

Comment: Verifying the point is within the shape, that's a little tricky, but I think I've got one for you. Assuming you already measured the distance between the point and each segment, a clean solution is to check if the dis between the closest segment to the point and the furthest segment from the point is less or more than the dis between the point and its furthest segment.  To simplify: assume L1 is the closest segment to P, and L2 is the furthest segment to P. If Dis(P, L2) > Dis (L1, L2) --> P is out of the shape. If Dis(P, L2) <= Dis (L1, L2) --> P is within the shape.

Answer (score 1):

Let's split the problem into two parts:

### Finding the nearest point

This can be done either via simple bruteforce, or using a [KD-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree), depending on how often you'll run a query for the same data-structure.

### Determining whether the point lies inside the polygon

This one depends heavily on the shape you're working with. For rectangles it's trivial. For a polygon without holes, you can use the [winding number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number) to determine whether you're inside the polygon. If the structure becomes even more complex your best bet will be a [sweep line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `java.awt.Polygon` class for this. It implements the `Shape` interface.

```
Polygon b = new Polygon();
        
b.addPoint(0,100);
b.addPoint(100,100);
b.addPoint(100,0);
b.addPoint(0,0);
        
System.out.println(b.contains(10,10));
System.out.println(b.contains(10,1000));
```

prints

```
true
false
```

Comment: ah cool! Anyway to find the closest point?